# Inverse map for an ODE

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let us consider the Cauchy problem:
$$y'(t)=f(t,y(t))$$with initial data $$y(t_0)=y_0$$
Suppose that the solution exists and we denote it by $y(t,y_0)$, and we consider the map $$y_0 \rightarrow y(t,y_0)$$
Is this function is well-defined? What can we say about its regularity? and properties?

Thanks.

Comment: It is well-defined if $f$ is continuous and globally Lipschitz in the $y$ argument. If you only get that $f$ is locally Lipschitz, then it is not guaranteed that $t$ is inside the domain of the maximal solution for every $y_0$.

Comment: Yes, I have assumed that the solution exists globally. Can you provide me some references about that?

Comment: I think about the implicit function therorem. I believe that this solve the problem.